# Is there any way to exclude MathJax processing from certain HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax

Is there any way to exclude MathJax processing from certain HTML elements?

If for example I know that there is not any math in a `<div>`, is there a way to mark it so that the MathJax processor skips that `<div>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both MathJax's TeX and AsciiMath input pre-processors offer a configuration option `ignoreClass` to ignore elements by class name, see e.g., [the tex2jax documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/tex2jax.html). The MathML pre-processor does not have such an option, cf. [this feature request](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/505).

Still, except in cases where the DOM is very large (and the occurrence of math is very localized), the pre-processing is not a significant performance bottleneck.

Comment: great -- i was hoping there would be this kind of feature but didn't know where to look. thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there is. Use the `tex2jax_ignore` CSS class:

```
 <div class="tex2jax_ignore"> $$ \frac{1}{2} $$ - Content not parsed by Mathjax</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xfjqze00/3/

Hope that helps.

**Update:**

As I found out while writing [this post](https://www.mathelounge.de/509545/mathjax-latex-basic-tutorial-und-referenz-deutsch) (see Mathjax in action there), Mathjax does also ignore code that is within the HTML `<code>` tag.

Comment: This solution depends on actual values of `skipTags` and `ignoreClass` [params](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/preprocessors/tex2jax.html?highlight=skipTags) of [MathJax config](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/configuration.html).