# Is there any way to exclude MathJax 3 processing from certain HTML elements?

Tags: html, mathjax

Using MathJax 2, to ignore typesetting a tag, adding the `asciimath2jax_ignore` class to the tag was sufficient for ignoring a tag for the AsciiMath input processor.

```
<p class="asciimath2jax_ignore">This won't be typeset</p>
```

The entire document could be ignore by the following means:

```
<body class="asciimath2jax_ignore">
...
</body>
```

Is there a way to achieve the same using MathJax 3 (I'm using the AsciiMath input processor)?

Comment: tex2jax_ignore appears to be MathJax 2 only https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39935447/is-there-any-way-to-exclude-mathjax-processing-from-certain-html-elements

Comment: You could turn off initial typesetting of the entire document and then manually typeset only the parts you'd like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that using the `ignoreHtmlClass` option in the `options` section of your configuration.  For example:

```html
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
<script>
MathJax = {
  loader: {load: ['input/asciimath', 'output/chtml', 'ui/menu', 
  'a11y/assistive-mml']},
  options: {
    ignoreHtmlClass: 'asciimath2jax_ignore'
  }
}
</script>
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/startup.js"></script>

<p>
This is processed: `x^2+1`
</p>
<p class="asciimath2jax_ignore">
This is not:  `x^2+1`
</p>
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/document.html) for more details.